# php7 alpine not loading libraries. I suspect incorrect versions

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to get laravel dusk running in bitbucket pipelines. I've found this discussion about doing it but the steps aren't working for me.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Running-Laravel-Dusk-in-BitBucket-Pipelines/qaq-p/621910

I'm just trying to get to the point where I have composer installed in my project.

I can get the docker image:

```
docker run --privileged -ti angelomaragna/networld-dusk /bin/sh
```

I then update the repository

```
/var/www # apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function properly.
v3.7.0-5225-gf676af6ec9 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main]
v3.7.0-5224-g88cb5720c4 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community]
OK: 9623 distinct packages available
```

And add a few extra dependencies that composer complains about it they're missing

```
/var/www # apk add php7-xmlwriter php7-pdo_mysql php7-session php7-ctype
WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function properly.
(1/6) Installing php7-ctype (7.2.5-r0)
(2/6) Installing php7-pdo (7.2.5-r0)
(3/6) Installing php7-mysqlnd (7.2.5-r0)
(4/6) Installing php7-pdo_mysql (7.2.5-r0)
(5/6) Installing php7-session (7.2.5-r0)
(6/6) Installing php7-xmlwriter (7.2.5-r0)
OK: 314 MiB in 151 packages
/var/www #
/var/www # (5/6) Installing php7-session (7.2.5-r0)
/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected word
/var/www #
/var/www # (5/6) Installing php7-session (7.2.5-r0)
/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected word
```

**Install composer: this is where things go wrong. I suspect I need a version less than 7.2 for the libraries about but I don't know how to get them**

```
/var/www # curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ctype: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20170718
PHP    compiled with module API=20160303
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/modules/pdo.so' - Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/pdo.so: zend_strpprintf: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/modules/session.so' - Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/session.so: zend_empty_string: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/modules/xmlwriter.so' - Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/xmlwriter.so: zend_empty_string: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/modules/mysqlnd.so' - Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/mysqlnd.so: zend_vspprintf: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/pdo_mysql.so: mysqlnd_allocator: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
```

How do I find previous version and what version would correspond to module API 20160303

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I needed to change the repository from edge to v3.7 then run `apk update`

/etc/apk/repositories:

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community
```